# Cumulative aggregates within tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

say I have a  `tibble` (or `data.table`) which consists of two columns:

```
a <- tibble(id = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 6), val = c(1, 0, 0, 1 ,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1))
```

Furthermore I have a function called `myfun` which takes a numeric vector of arbitrary length as input and returns a single number. For example, you can think of `myfun` as being the standard deviation.

Now I would like to create a third column  to my `tibble` (called result) which contains the outputs of `myfun` applied to val cumulated and grouped with respect to id.
For example, the first entry of result should contain `mfun(val[1])`.
The second entry should contain `myfun(val[1:2])`, and so on.
I would like to implent a cumulated version of myfun.

Of course there a lot of easy solutions outside the `tidyverse` using loops and what not.
But I would be interested in a solution within the `tidyverse` or within the `data.table` frame work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
library(tidyverse)

a %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(y = map_dbl(seq_along(val),~sd(val[1:.x]))) %>%
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 12 x 3
#       id   val         y
#    <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1     A     1        NA
#  2     A     0 0.7071068
#  3     A     0 0.5773503
#  4     A     1 0.5773503
#  5     A     0 0.5477226
#  6     A     1 0.5477226
#  7     B     0        NA
#  8     B     0 0.0000000
#  9     B     0 0.0000000
# 10     B     1 0.5000000
# 11     B     1 0.5477226
# 12     B     1 0.5477226
```

**Explanation**

We first group like often with `tidyverse` chains, then we use `mutate`, and not `summarize`, as we want to keep the same unaggregated rows.

The function `map_dbl` is here used to loop on a vector of final indices. `seq_along(val)` will be `1:6` for both groups here.

Using functions from the map family we can use the `~` notation, which will assume the first parameter of the function is named `.x`.

Looping through these indices we compute first `sd(val[1:1])` which is `sd(val[1])` which is `NA`, then `sd(val[1:2])` etc...

`map_dbl` returns by design a vector of `doubles`, and these are stacked in the `y` column.

Comment: glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 2):

One can use `zoo::rollapplyr` with dynamic width (`vector containing width`). To prepare a dynamic width for each group `1:n()` or `seq(n())` can be used.

Let's apply it for function `sd` using data provided by `OP` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

a %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(y = rollapplyr(val, 1:n(), sd ))

#   # Groups: id [2]
#   id      val      y
#   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 A      1.00 NA    
#  2 A      0     0.707
#  3 A      0     0.577
#  4 A      1.00  0.577
#  5 A      0     0.548
#  6 A      1.00  0.548
#  7 B      0    NA    
#  8 B      0     0    
#  9 B      0     0    
# 10 B      1.00  0.500
# 11 B      1.00  0.548
# 12 B      1.00  0.548
```