# How to vectorize nested loops and update a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have a dataframe with a column called Product (with many products), a column called Timestamp (representing the date in a discrete ordinal variable) and a column called Rating.
I am trying to calculate the moving average and the moving standard deviation for the Rating variable, by each Product, taking into account the Timestamp.

The data looks something like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(Product=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c"),
             Timestamp=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5),
             Rating=c(4,3,5,3,3,4,5,3,1,1,2,5))
```

Now I add the columns for the moving average and the moving standard deviation:

```
DF$Moving.avg <- rep(0,nrow(DF))
DF$Moving.sd <- rep(0,nrow(DF))
```

And finally, I am using this code with nested for loops to get the result I want:

```
for (product in unique(DF$Product)) {
  for (timestamp in DF[DF$Product==product,]$Timestamp){
    if (timestamp==1) {
      DF[DF$Product==product &
           DF$Timestamp==timestamp,]$Moving.avg <- 
        DF[DF$Product==product &
             DF$Timestamp==timestamp,]$Rating
      DF[DF$Product==product &
           DF$Timestamp==timestamp,]$Moving.sd <- 0
    }else{
      index_start <- which(DF$Product==product &
                             DF$Timestamp==1)
      index_end <- which(DF$Product==product &
                           DF$Timestamp==timestamp)
      DF[DF$Product==product &
           DF$Timestamp==timestamp,]$Moving.avg <- 
        mean(DF[index_start:index_end,]$Rating)
  
      DF[DF$Product==product &
           DF$Timestamp==timestamp,]$Moving.sd <- 
        sd(DF[index_start:index_end,]$Rating)
    }
  }
}
```

The code works fine but it is too slow.
I wonder how can I use vectorization to make this faster?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the whole thing vectorised in base R you could try:

```r
DF <- data.frame(Product=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c"),
             Timestamp=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5),
             Rating=c(4,3,5,3,3,4,5,3,1,1,2,5))

cbind(DF, do.call(rbind, lapply(split(DF, DF$Product), function(x) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(x)), function(y) {
    c(Moving.avg = mean(x$Rating[1:y]), Moving.sd = sd(x$Rating[1:y]))}))})))

#>    Product Timestamp Rating Moving.avg Moving.sd
#> 1        a         1      4   4.000000        NA
#> 2        a         2      3   3.500000 0.7071068
#> 3        a         3      5   4.000000 1.0000000
#> 4        a         4      3   3.750000 0.9574271
#> 5        b         1      3   3.000000        NA
#> 6        b         2      4   3.500000 0.7071068
#> 7        b         3      5   4.000000 1.0000000
#> 8        c         1      3   3.000000        NA
#> 9        c         2      1   2.000000 1.4142136
#> 10       c         3      1   1.666667 1.1547005
#> 11       c         4      2   1.750000 0.9574271
#> 12       c         5      5   2.400000 1.6733201
```

Note though that the `sd` of a single number is `NA` rather than 0. It would be simple to replace these if desired by `DF$Moving.sd[is.na(DF$Moving.sd)] <- 0`

<sup>Created on 2020-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Allan. I have a question related to your code. You did not take into account the variable Timestamp to calculate the moving average for each row in your script. How does R know what order should be used for the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for cumulative mean and cumulative standard deviation.

For cumulative mean you can use `cummean` function and `TTR::runSD` for cumulative standard deviation.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  mutate(cum_avg = cummean(Rating), 
         cum_std = TTR::runSD(Rating, n = 1, cumulative = TRUE))

#  Product Timestamp Rating cum_avg cum_std
#   <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 a               1      4    4    NaN    
# 2 a               2      3    3.5    0.707
# 3 a               3      5    4      1    
# 4 a               4      3    3.75   0.957
# 5 b               1      3    3    NaN    
# 6 b               2      4    3.5    0.707
# 7 b               3      5    4      1    
# 8 c               1      3    3    NaN    
# 9 c               2      1    2      1.41 
#10 c               3      1    1.67   1.15 
#11 c               4      2    1.75   0.957
#12 c               5      5    2.4    1.67
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ronak. I have the same question I asked Allan, related to your simpler code. You did not take into account the variable Timestamp to calculate the moving average for each row in your script. How does R know what order should be used for the calculation?

Comment: If the `Timestamp` is not always ordered you can order the data first. In `dplyr` you can do it via `arrange` like  `DF %>% arrange(Timestamp) %>%  group_by(Product).....rest of the code as it is.`

Answer (score 0):

Does this example works for you? Here I am using the function runner() from runner package. The runner() will apply a function, on the window that you define, and works fine with the group_by() function from dplyr. You define the size of window of the function, on the k argument.

```
library(runner)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

DF <- data.frame(Product=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c"),
                 Timestamp=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5),
                 Rating=c(4,3,5,3,3,4,5,3,1,1,2,5))


DF <- DF %>% 
  group_by(Product) %>% 
  arrange(Timestamp, .by_group = T)


DF <- DF %>% 
  mutate(
    average = runner(Rating, f = function(x) mean(x), k = 3),
    deviation = runner(Rating, f = function(x) sd(x), k = 3)
  )
```

Is worth mention, that the function will expand the window size on the fisrt lines of each group (or each Product) on your data.frame, until reach the size defined on k argument. So in the first two lines, where we still not have 3 previous values, runner() will apply the function on these two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599976/cumulative-aggregates-within-tidyverse) answer to a related question, you could also do it this way with `dplyr`:

```
DF <- DF %>% 
  # Sort in order of product and then timestamp within product 
  arrange(Product, Timestamp) %>% 
  # group data by product
  group_by(Product) %>% 
  # use the cumulative mean function to calculate the means 
  mutate(Moving.avg = cummean(Rating), 
    # use the map_dbl function to calculate standard deviations up to a certain index value       
    Moving.sd = map_dbl(seq_along(Timestamp),~sd(Rating[1:.x])), 
    # replace Moving.sd=0 when Timestamp takes on its smallest value
    Moving.sd = case_when(Timestamp == min(Timestamp) ~ 0, 
                        TRUE ~ Moving.sd)) %>%
  # ungroup the data
  ungroup
```